# Saving critical errors using logging Python

Tags: python, exception, logging

I made a little game as my school project & i want to save critical errors to my .log file that I had created using logging module, but i just can't figure out how to log them.

Logging configuration:

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, filename='log.log', filemode='w', format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s:%(levelname)s: %(message)s')
```

What i want to do:
Every time a program will encounter exception, that can't be handled (like TypeError or SyntaxError) it will be saved in log.log file. Then program will exit. But it usually just close program and pritn error in terminal, which is not intended.

I have tried to use:

```
import sys
class ShutdownHandler(logging.Handler):
    def emit(self, record):
        logging.critical(record.msg)
        logging.shutdown()
        sys.exit(1)
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, filename='log.log', filemode='w', format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s:%(levelname)s: %(message)s')
```

But it didn't saved output to log.log file. Instead i have got error message in terminal.

Comment: You can use `try`, `except` blocks, you try some running some code, and in case there is an exception you can handle it in the except block

Comment: @AtharvaGundawar That's not what i meant. I want to save critical errors (those one that closes window, like Syntax Error) in log file.

Comment: You can run the target file using another python file with the help of the `subprocess` or a similar package and log the output.

Comment: @AtharvaGundawar Will I be able to save logs to the same file from 2 scripts, or there have to be additional crash.log?

Answer (score 0):

As discussed above you can use the following to record any errors which will be returned to you in the terminal :

```py
import subprocess

a = subprocess.run(["python3","hello.py"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print(a.stdout.decode('utf-8'))
```

Once you have the output, you can search for errors ad log your experiments accordingly .